# Как получить данные вложенного списка в mongoDb?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2, mongodb

У меня есть вот такая структура:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("18b97aa654bce61356002559"),
        "name" : "Photo",
        "childs" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("18b97aa654bce41356002559"),
                "name" : "Photo childs",
                "childs" : [ 
                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("88b55aa654bce61356000000"),
                        "name" : "Photo childs childs",
                        "childs" :  [ 
                           {
                             "_id" : ObjectId("33b55aa654bce61356000000"),//нужно получить данные этого вложенного документа
                             "name" : "Photo childs childs childs",
                             "childs" : ""
                           }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Глубина вложенности может быть любая то есть

- childs
- -childs
- --childs
- ---childs
- ----childs
- ...... бесконечно

Как можно найти любого вложенного children?

```
$arr = Categories::findOne(['_id' => '33b55aa654bce61356000000']); //таким образом я не смогу найти любой элемент, только первый
var_dump($arr)
```

Есть ли еще какие-то способы получить такие данные?
Или может нужно пересмотреть структуру БД?
как вообще лучше организовать базу к примеру магазина с вложеными категориями и продуктами в них?
Спасибо.

Comment: Как-то очень фигово это сделано. Да еще и в монге.